# Android Studio drawable is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-studio-2.2

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 5.

When I try to render a layout, it displays following error:

```
Rendering Problems

java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: @android:drawable/ic_menu_send
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.parseFileName(ResourceItem.java:585)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.parseXmlToResourceValue(ResourceItem.java:405)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.getResourceValue(ResourceItem.java:240)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.AbstractResourceRepository.getConfiguredResources(AbstractResourceRepository.java:393)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.AbstractResourceRepository.getConfiguredResources(AbstractResourceRepository.java:349)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache$1.compute(ResourceResolverCache.java:166)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache$1.compute(ResourceResolverCache.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache.getResourceResolver(ResourceResolverCache.java:163)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.Configuration.getResourceResolver(Configuration.java:1212)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.getResourceResolver(RenderTask.java:198)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:425)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$52(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I looked in the folder for android-19 and android-23:

```
sdk/platforms/android-**/data/res/drawable
```

But in neither of these is the file ic_menu_send.xml

My xml file contained a `src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"` once, but I removed it and chose another icon.

Then there was a `ic_menu_send.xml` (v21) in my res folder, so I deleted it because I didn't need it anymore.

If that was the reason, could someone please send me the `ic_menu_send.xml` file for the 2 versions or tell me how I can redownload all drawables?

Comment: What if you add your own drawable?

Comment: What should I put in it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you deleted was an xml file, but an image file. So here you go:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBWSc.png

Just save it as 'ic_menu_send.png' and put it back in that folder.

Comment: there is already a ic_menu_send.png in data/res/drawable-hdpi but there isn't a ic_menu_send.xml in data/res/drawable

Comment: Sorry I don't have that. Which particular sdk are you using?